# .Net hosting with MCR Matlab installed or integration

Tags: asp.net, matlab, web-hosting, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to find some hosting for a .Net application uses a dll generated from Matlab.

in another way...

How to deploy a Matlab function on a .Net compiler SDK to another .Net application **and host** this application in some .Net hosting site.

Is there is any hosting sites supporting integration with MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) or not?

like [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94298-why-do-i-receive-an-error-regarding-missing-mclmcrrt7x-dll-when-i-run-my-stand-alone-application-com) says, it's a must to have MCR installed on the deployment machine for a . Net compiler SDK.

if not what is the alternatives so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searches, I have found only one useful solution!

[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/9i2knk/net_hosting_with_mcr_matlab_installed_or/) you can find the question and answer.

[image: After a lot of searches I have found only one useful solution!]